# Time complexity of shortest path algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, queue, dijkstra, breadth-first-search

So I wrote an algorithm that finds the number of distinct shortest paths in an undirected, unweighted graph. I believe it is correct and I'm having trouble figuring out what the running time is. All help is greatly appreciated!

```
shortestPaths(undirected graph G, startNode v, endNode end)
    initialize  all levels of nodes to -1
    count = 1;
    initialize queue Q = {v}
    level(v) = 0

    while Q is not empty
        curr = pop(Q)

        if( curr == end)
            w = pop(Q)
            while(level(w)==level(curr))
                if(w == end)
                    count++
                w=pop(Q)
            return count

        for all neighbors (nxt) of node curr do 
            if( level(nxt) == -1 )
                level(nxt) = level(curr) + 1
                Push(Q, nxt)
            else if( level(nxt) == level(curr) + 1 )
                Push(Q, nxt)
            else if( level(nxt) > level(curr) + 1)
                Level(nxt) = Level(curr) + 1
    return count
```

Comment: Certainly exponential. At least O(2^(|V|/2)), and probably not more that O(2^|V|).  Not good considering that you can do this in O(|V|+|E|) time.

Comment: how could I achieve O(|V| + |E|)

Comment: I am confused. Without trying to understand the code: There should be only one shortest path between start and end, right? What are then distinct shortest paths?

Comment: because there may be two distinct paths of the same length, where both are the shortest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run time of your algorithm is exponential. You can avoid this by not pushing a vertex into heap several times, but instead by associating a counter with every vertex and incrementing it with every new path to this vertex.

Try something like this:

```
initialize  all counts of nodes to 0                     // added
counts(v) = 1                                            // added
...
while Q is not empty
    curr = pop(Q)

    if( curr == end)
        return counts(curr)

    for all neighbors (nxt) of node curr do 
        if( level(nxt) == -1 )
            level(nxt) = level(curr) + 1
            counts(nxt) = counts(curr)                   // added
            Push(Q, nxt)
        else if( level(nxt) == level(curr) + 1 )
            counts(nxt) += counts(curr)                  // added & removed
return 0
```

And this has the same complexity as [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) - `O(|E|+|V|)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Yola, I am a bit confused as to what it returned. Is it the counds(end node)? or the max of counts

Comment: @RaoulDuke i've updated the code, as soon as we pop end node, we are done -- its counter must contain number of paths to it. If we never reach end node, so there is no paths to it.

Comment: I think I got it actually. In the code you wrote, I think I could also take out the w = popQ and the while loop and just return count(end). Again, thanks for your help. it makes a lot more sense

Comment: @RaoulDuke glad i helped. I want to point out as well that you don't need the third condition. You need to check only in Dijkstra not in BFS.

Comment: Awesome. its crystal clear now. Im guessing that it is O(|E| + |V|) because in the worse case the max edges travelled is equal to the distance between start and destination nodes (|E|)? Plus initialization accounts for |V|

Comment: @RaoulDuke yes, you might need to explore all edges.

Comment: yes, that makes sense. I don't think it was necessary in the first place either!